# Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 322122 5785

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Have my geckodriver in PATH and tried everything but still not able to fix it.

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 322122
>   5785

Environment:

**geckodriver** - v0.19.1

**Python** - 3.4

**selenium** - 3.13

**firefox** - 52

**OS** - WIN XP 2003

Comment: windows xp is outdated. are you using still?

Comment: yeah. I'm using win xp because don't have any other option but I think this has nothing to do with above problem,right?